# Why is mysql-server not installing correctly?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, amazon-web-services, lamp

I just launched a brand-new t4g.nano instance on AWS EC2. The first thing I typed in is `apt update; apt upgrade; apt install mysql-server-8.0`. Here's the full log:

```
$ ssh -i ~/downloads/*.pem ubuntu@[ip]
The authenticity of host '[ip]' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:[key].
This key is not known by any other names.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '[ip]' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.19.0-1025-aws aarch64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Wed Jun 28 21:48:52 UTC 2023

  System load:  0.39404296875     Processes:             140
  Usage of /:   19.4% of 7.58GB   Users logged in:       0
  Memory usage: 49%               IPv4 address for ens5: [ip]
  Swap usage:   0%

Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is not enabled.

0 updates can be applied immediately.

Enable ESM Apps to receive additional future security updates.
See https://ubuntu.com/esm or run: sudo pro status


The list of available updates is more than a week old.
To check for new updates run: sudo apt update


The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.

To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.

ubuntu@[ip]:~$ sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade; sudo apt install mysql-server-8.0
### I'm not including the update/upgrade log here ###
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libclone-perl libencode-locale-perl libevent-pthreads-2.1-7 libfcgi-bin libfcgi-perl libfcgi0ldbl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl
  libhtml-template-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libio-html-perl liblwp-mediatypes-perl libmecab2 libprotobuf-lite23 libtimedate-perl liburi-perl mecab-ipadic
  mecab-ipadic-utf8 mecab-utils mysql-client-8.0 mysql-client-core-8.0 mysql-common mysql-server-core-8.0
Suggested packages:
  libdata-dump-perl libipc-sharedcache-perl libbusiness-isbn-perl libwww-perl mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libclone-perl libencode-locale-perl libevent-pthreads-2.1-7 libfcgi-bin libfcgi-perl libfcgi0ldbl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl
  libhtml-template-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libio-html-perl liblwp-mediatypes-perl libmecab2 libprotobuf-lite23 libtimedate-perl liburi-perl mecab-ipadic
  mecab-ipadic-utf8 mecab-utils mysql-client-8.0 mysql-client-core-8.0 mysql-common mysql-server-8.0 mysql-server-core-8.0
0 upgraded, 27 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 28.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 238 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://us-west-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main arm64 mysql-common all 5.8+1.0.8 [7212 B]
Get:2 http://us-west-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/main arm64 mysql-client-core-8.0 arm64 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 [2915 kB]
Get:3 http://us-west-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/main arm64 mysql-client-8.0 arm64 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 [22.7 kB]
Get:4 http://us-west-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main arm64 libevent-pthreads-2.1-7 arm64 2.1.12-stable-1build3 [7588 B]
Get:5 http://us-west-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main arm64 libmecab2 arm64 0.996-14build9 [188 kB]
Get:6 http://us-west-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/main arm64 libprotobuf-lite23 arm64 3.12.4-1ubuntu7.22.04.1 [192 kB]
Get:7 http://us-west-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/main arm64 mysql-server-core-8.0 arm64 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 [16.7 MB]
Get:8 http://us-west-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/main arm64 mysql-server-8.0 arm64 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 [1232 kB]
Get:9 http://us-west-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main arm64 libhtml-tagset-perl all 3.20-4 [12.5 kB]
Get:10 http://us-west-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main arm64 liburi-perl all 5.10-1 [78.8 kB]
Get:11 http://us-west-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main arm64 libhtml-parser-perl arm64 3.76-1build2 [87.1 kB]
Get:12 http://us-west-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main arm64 libcgi-pm-perl all 4.54-1 [188 kB]
Get:13 http://us-west-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main arm64 libfcgi0ldbl arm64 2.4.2-2build2 [28.0 kB]
Get:14 http://us-west-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main arm64 libfcgi-perl arm64 0.82+ds-1build1 [22.3 kB]
Get:15 http://us-west-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main arm64 libcgi-fast-perl all 1:2.15-1 [10.5 kB]
Get:16 http://us-west-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main arm64 libclone-perl arm64 0.45-1build3 [10.8 kB]
Get:17 http://us-west-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main arm64 libencode-locale-perl all 1.05-1.1 [11.8 kB]
Get:18 http://us-west-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main arm64 libfcgi-bin arm64 2.4.2-2build2 [10.7 kB]
Get:19 http://us-west-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main arm64 libhtml-template-perl all 2.97-1.1 [59.1 kB]
Get:20 http://us-west-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main arm64 libtimedate-perl all 2.3300-2 [34.0 kB]
Get:21 http://us-west-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main arm64 libhttp-date-perl all 6.05-1 [9920 B]
Get:22 http://us-west-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main arm64 libio-html-perl all 1.004-2 [15.4 kB]
Get:23 http://us-west-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main arm64 liblwp-mediatypes-perl all 6.04-1 [19.5 kB]
Get:24 http://us-west-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main arm64 libhttp-message-perl all 6.36-1 [76.8 kB]
Get:25 http://us-west-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main arm64 mecab-utils arm64 0.996-14build9 [4830 B]
Get:26 http://us-west-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main arm64 mecab-ipadic all 2.7.0-20070801+main-3 [6718 kB]
Get:27 http://us-west-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main arm64 mecab-ipadic-utf8 all 2.7.0-20070801+main-3 [4384 B]
Fetched 28.7 MB in 1s (36.1 MB/s)            
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
(Reading database ... 96282 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-mysql-common_5.8+1.0.8_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.8+1.0.8) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-core-8.0.
Preparing to unpack .../1-mysql-client-core-8.0_8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-core-8.0 (8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-8.0.
Preparing to unpack .../2-mysql-client-8.0_8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-8.0 (8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libevent-pthreads-2.1-7:arm64.
Preparing to unpack .../3-libevent-pthreads-2.1-7_2.1.12-stable-1build3_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking libevent-pthreads-2.1-7:arm64 (2.1.12-stable-1build3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmecab2:arm64.
Preparing to unpack .../4-libmecab2_0.996-14build9_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking libmecab2:arm64 (0.996-14build9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libprotobuf-lite23:arm64.
Preparing to unpack .../5-libprotobuf-lite23_3.12.4-1ubuntu7.22.04.1_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking libprotobuf-lite23:arm64 (3.12.4-1ubuntu7.22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-8.0.
Preparing to unpack .../6-mysql-server-core-8.0_8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-8.0 (8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.8+1.0.8) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-8.0.
(Reading database ... 96496 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-mysql-server-8.0_8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhtml-tagset-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../01-libhtml-tagset-perl_3.20-4_all.deb ...
Unpacking libhtml-tagset-perl (3.20-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liburi-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../02-liburi-perl_5.10-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking liburi-perl (5.10-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhtml-parser-perl:arm64.
Preparing to unpack .../03-libhtml-parser-perl_3.76-1build2_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking libhtml-parser-perl:arm64 (3.76-1build2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcgi-pm-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../04-libcgi-pm-perl_4.54-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libcgi-pm-perl (4.54-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfcgi0ldbl:arm64.
Preparing to unpack .../05-libfcgi0ldbl_2.4.2-2build2_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking libfcgi0ldbl:arm64 (2.4.2-2build2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfcgi-perl:arm64.
Preparing to unpack .../06-libfcgi-perl_0.82+ds-1build1_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking libfcgi-perl:arm64 (0.82+ds-1build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcgi-fast-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../07-libcgi-fast-perl_1%3a2.15-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libcgi-fast-perl (1:2.15-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libclone-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../08-libclone-perl_0.45-1build3_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking libclone-perl (0.45-1build3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libencode-locale-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../09-libencode-locale-perl_1.05-1.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libencode-locale-perl (1.05-1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfcgi-bin.
Preparing to unpack .../10-libfcgi-bin_2.4.2-2build2_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking libfcgi-bin (2.4.2-2build2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhtml-template-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../11-libhtml-template-perl_2.97-1.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libhtml-template-perl (2.97-1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libtimedate-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../12-libtimedate-perl_2.3300-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libtimedate-perl (2.3300-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhttp-date-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../13-libhttp-date-perl_6.05-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libhttp-date-perl (6.05-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libio-html-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../14-libio-html-perl_1.004-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libio-html-perl (1.004-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblwp-mediatypes-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../15-liblwp-mediatypes-perl_6.04-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking liblwp-mediatypes-perl (6.04-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhttp-message-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../16-libhttp-message-perl_6.36-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libhttp-message-perl (6.36-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mecab-utils.
Preparing to unpack .../17-mecab-utils_0.996-14build9_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking mecab-utils (0.996-14build9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mecab-ipadic.
Preparing to unpack .../18-mecab-ipadic_2.7.0-20070801+main-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking mecab-ipadic (2.7.0-20070801+main-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mecab-ipadic-utf8.
Preparing to unpack .../19-mecab-ipadic-utf8_2.7.0-20070801+main-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking mecab-ipadic-utf8 (2.7.0-20070801+main-3) ...
Setting up libmecab2:arm64 (0.996-14build9) ...
Setting up mysql-client-core-8.0 (8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
Setting up libfcgi0ldbl:arm64 (2.4.2-2build2) ...
Setting up libclone-perl (0.45-1build3) ...
Setting up libhtml-tagset-perl (3.20-4) ...
Setting up liblwp-mediatypes-perl (6.04-1) ...
Setting up libfcgi-bin (2.4.2-2build2) ...
Setting up libencode-locale-perl (1.05-1.1) ...
Setting up libprotobuf-lite23:arm64 (3.12.4-1ubuntu7.22.04.1) ...
Setting up mecab-utils (0.996-14build9) ...
Setting up libio-html-perl (1.004-2) ...
Setting up libtimedate-perl (2.3300-2) ...
Setting up mysql-client-8.0 (8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
Setting up libfcgi-perl:arm64 (0.82+ds-1build1) ...
Setting up liburi-perl (5.10-1) ...
Setting up libevent-pthreads-2.1-7:arm64 (2.1.12-stable-1build3) ...
Setting up libhttp-date-perl (6.05-1) ...
Setting up mecab-ipadic (2.7.0-20070801+main-3) ...
Compiling IPA dictionary for Mecab.  This takes long time...
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/unk.def ... 40
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################| 
/usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/model.def is not found. skipped.
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Interjection.csv ... 252
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.proper.csv ... 27328
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.nai.csv ... 42
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.adverbal.csv ... 795
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.place.csv ... 72999
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Auxil.csv ... 199
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.demonst.csv ... 120
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.number.csv ... 42
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Filler.csv ... 19
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.csv ... 60477
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Suffix.csv ... 1393
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.org.csv ... 16668
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Others.csv ... 2
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.others.csv ... 151
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Symbol.csv ... 208
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Conjunction.csv ... 171
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adnominal.csv ... 135
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Prefix.csv ... 221
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Postp-col.csv ... 91
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.adjv.csv ... 3328
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adverb.csv ... 3032
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.verbal.csv ... 12146
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Postp.csv ... 146
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adj.csv ... 27210
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.name.csv ... 34202
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Verb.csv ... 130750
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################| 
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/matrix.def ... 1316x1316
emitting matrix      : 100% |###########################################| 

done!
update-alternatives: using /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic to provide /var/lib/mecab/dic/debian (mecab-dictionary) in auto mode
Setting up mysql-server-core-8.0 (8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
Setting up mecab-ipadic-utf8 (2.7.0-20070801+main-3) ...
Compiling IPA dictionary for Mecab.  This takes long time...
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/unk.def ... 40
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################| 
/usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/model.def is not found. skipped.
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Interjection.csv ... 252
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.proper.csv ... 27328
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.nai.csv ... 42
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.adverbal.csv ... 795
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.place.csv ... 72999
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Auxil.csv ... 199
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.demonst.csv ... 120
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.number.csv ... 42
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Filler.csv ... 19
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.csv ... 60477
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Suffix.csv ... 1393
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.org.csv ... 16668
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Others.csv ... 2
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.others.csv ... 151
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Symbol.csv ... 208
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Conjunction.csv ... 171
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adnominal.csv ... 135
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Prefix.csv ... 221
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Postp-col.csv ... 91
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.adjv.csv ... 3328
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adverb.csv ... 3032
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.verbal.csv ... 12146
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Postp.csv ... 146
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adj.csv ... 27210
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.name.csv ... 34202
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Verb.csv ... 130750
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################| 
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/matrix.def ... 1316x1316
emitting matrix      : 100% |###########################################| 

done!
update-alternatives: using /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic-utf8 to provide /var/lib/mecab/dic/debian (mecab-dictionary) in auto mode
Setting up libhtml-parser-perl:arm64 (3.76-1build2) ...
Setting up libhttp-message-perl (6.36-1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-8.0.postinst: line 21: 19937 Killed                  mysqld --user=mysql --daemonize --socket="$tmpdir/mysqld.sock" --pid-file="$tmpdir/mysqld.pid" --skip-networking
Warning: Unable to start the server.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.service → /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service.
Job for mysql.service failed.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xeu mysql.service" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: oom-kill) since Wed 2023-06-28 21:51:29 UTC; 29ms ago
    Process: 20010 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 20018 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=killed, signal=KILL)
   Main PID: 20018 (code=killed, signal=KILL)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
        CPU: 274ms

Jun 28 21:51:29 ip-172-31-53-175 systemd[1]: mysql.service: A process of this unit has been killed by the OOM killer.
Jun 28 21:51:29 ip-172-31-53-175 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Jun 28 21:51:29 ip-172-31-53-175 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
Jun 28 21:51:29 ip-172-31-53-175 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up libcgi-pm-perl (4.54-1) ...
Setting up libhtml-template-perl (2.97-1.1) ...
Setting up libcgi-fast-perl (1:2.15-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
ubuntu@[ip]:~$
```

Notice the error at the end. Why does `mysql-server` fail to install? What am I doing wrong, and how else should I install it?

Answer (score 1):

> `A process of this unit has been killed by the OOM killer.`

The issue was that it was running out of RAM (t4g.nano only has 0.5 GB). I fixed it by creating a swapfile ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17173973)):

```
sudo /bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024
sudo /sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
sudo chmod 600 /var/swap.1
sudo /sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
```